# How to return a list of lists from a recursive function in scala?

Tags: scala, list, recursion

I am creating a function that must return a List of Lists. So The function takes a List as its argument and it then does some calculations involving the data in this list. What the function does to the list is irrelevant to solving my problem, however the function calls itself on data in the list, modifying it slightly. What I need to do, is when the base case is reached, I need every variation of the list that has made it to the base case to then be added to the list to be returned.

The structure of the function is as follows:

```
def foo(last: List[Int]) : List[List[Int]] = {
  if(condition){
    *return the List[List[Int]]
  }
  else{
    lst.foreach(x => foo(x :: lst))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might look to this pattern:

```
def foo[A](st: List[A]) : List[List[A]] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(ls: List[A]) = {
      if (condition) loop(ls.foreach(x => foo(x :: ls)).last)
      else ls
    }
    loop(st)
}
```

This is an **Implicit Polymorphic Function**.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper function inside of the foo function that is called by foo which takes a list of lists.

Initially, that function takes the original list inside of another list which you then append to through your recursive call.

You can then just return that list of lists when you reach the base case, and foo just returns whatever that helper function returned.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this -

In Recursive way with Pattern Matching (Not Tail Recursive)

```
@ def foo(lst: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = lst match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case h :: tail => List(h) :: foo(tail) // Put condition here 
                                     // case h :: t (condition) =>
}
defined function foo

@ foo(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))
List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3), List(4), List(5), List(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you structure it, you need every call to `foo` to return a partial solution. So, in the base case, pack the input list as a solution, and in the recursive case, merge all partial solutions together.

```
def foo(lst: List[Int]) : List[List[Int]] = {
  if(condition) {
    List(lst)
  }
  else {
    lst.flatMap(x => foo(x :: lst))
  }
}
```

This could get out of hand easily though as the recursion tree grows very fast, so you probably need a more efficient approach to your problem.